# Ajax API call results in CORS issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cors

I am trying to get an API response from [Sprout Video](http://sproutvideo.com) using their Javascript API. The issue is that I am getting a CORS issue on the request. I can get a response back in Postman, but not on my website.

I found a bunch of questions regarding this issue but so far have not been able to find a working solution for my scenario. I thought that adding the header `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'` was supposed to fix it but it doesn't. I also tried changing the dataType to `jsonp` which resulted in a different error, but still an error.

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

```
$.ajax({ 
        type : 'GET', 
        url : 'https://api.sproutvideo.com/v1/videos/' + videoID,
        headers: {
            'SproutVideo-Api-Key':'ae463680265ac2ff7bf6255b3488d0c1',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        crossDomain: true,
        success:function(result) { 
            console.log(result);
        }, 
        error:function(result) { 
            console.log(result); 
        } 
});
```

## [Here's a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z7x5m3bg/)

Comment: the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header needs to be on the response header, not the request header. I don't know enough about CORS to fix your issue but adding that header to the request isn't going to solve your problem.

Comment: As far as I can see from looking through the docs at http://sproutvideo.com/docs/api.html, trying to use the SproutVideo API directly from frontend JavaScript code isn’t supported—in particular, trying to call it from jQuery $.ajax or with XHR or the Fetch API. There is no mention in those docs of calling it from JavaScript code in any context. But anyway the assumption in the docs appears to be that you call it from backend code—for example, from backend PHP or Ruby code

Comment: Sorry, yeah, it seems like the problem is that the necessary Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header isn’t included in *any* responses from the API, but also more specifically, the API is not configured to respond correctly to the CORS preflight OPTIONS requests that browsers, automatically on their own, send as part of the CORS protocol. For the details of that, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests

Comment: Shouldn't your `dataType` be `jsonp` instead of `json`?

Answer (score 1):

I believe we were able to address this through customer support, but the SproutVideo API is not designed to be accessed using client-side javascript. The API allows you to completely control your account and therefore, your API key should be treated with the same care as you would your password to your account. In order to use the API on the client-side like you're attempting to do here, you'd expose your API key to anyone who visited you website which could have disastrous consequences.

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to access a secured protocol with an unsecured one, you will get this error. 
If this is your issue try changing your HTTP Protocol to being secured by either hosting it on a secured provider or if your project is Node.js based try uploading it to a secured service also. Let me know if that helped.

Comment: Thank you, but both the request and the response are happening over HTTPS as seen in the Fiddle.

Comment: Oh okay. Then i dont have a specific answer to your question sorry. But i have had this issue before if i recall i added some sort of chrome extension called Access-Control-Allow-Origin and i think that solved my problem, give it a shot and see if you can get it work, because i remember i had to play around with it to get it working.